# Как в Python сделать функцию, аргументом которой является массив (список)

Tags: python, массивы

Я написал функцию, однако когда я пытаюсь ей воспользоваться, она не работает. Подскажите, пожалуйста, что я делаю не так.

```
A = [0,2,1,2,0,5,2,4,3,4,5,2,4]
g = 10
def ccc(U, f):
    L = U.append(f)
    return L
print(ccc(A, g))
```

Comment: Что значит _"не работает"_? Раскройте, пожалуйста, мысль. Какая-то ошибка возникает? Мы ведь не знаем как она должна работать.

Comment: Во-первых, сделайте нормальное форматирование. Во-вторых, что, по Вашему мнению, возвращает `U.append(f)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Метод `append` возвращает `None`, поэтому присваивать результат переменной не нужно.

Сделано это для того, чтобы Вы <s>не прострелили себе ногу</s> не забыли о изменяемости списков.

Применение метода `append` даже в функции изменяет сам объект. То есть имя `A` тоже будет ссылаться на изменённый список, чего Вы навряд ли хотите.

Вам следует создать в функции новый список на основе переданного и вернуть уже его.

***Пример:***

```py
def f(li, x):
    return li + [x]
```